# How to set up rules in Gmail to send pre saved draft email

Tags: gmail

I have an email draft saved in Gmail and I want it to be sent when I receive an another email with a specific subject.

Comment: Look into canned responses.

Answer (score 1):

Try zapier integrations, they have a free tier for if you don't need to use it too often